# What's the best way to plan a 3D archery course?

Tags: preparation, archery, trails, 3d-archery

Let's say you want to establish a 3D archery tournament. You want to create a small 3D course.

You are at the stage where you want to make a concept for the trail. How do you create a map to ensure safety (shooting direction, terrain), to ensure that no one can get lost, and to gather some stats such as trail length and height?

Comment: What is the terrain like? Any course is going to be strongly dictated by the terrain and natural obstacles. A course going down gently sloped and moderately wooded 100 yard wide canyon is different than a two acre open park. Since you haven't specified anything about the terrain I feel this question is too broad.

Answer (score 2):

The NFAA has a great guide on how to create a field archery course.  The guide talks about minimum distances between targets, backstops and safe angles of approach.

https://www.nfaausa.com/wp-content/uploads/Archery-Range-Guidelines.pdf

The Easton Foundation also has a more illustrated guide to range design.

http://www.esdf.org/FacilityGuide/pdf/ArcheryFacilityPlanningGuide.pdf

My key takeaway: expect to use 1 acre per target.

Comment: This seems to be a link only answer

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh: kinda.  But the considerations are VERY detailed, and it doesn't make sense to replicate them.  As an archery range owner myself, I am very concerned with the details of safety angles, backstops etc, as it might be a liability issue.  Anybody could throw some 3d targets up and mark a trail otherwise.

Comment: My point is, you should summarize some of the most relevant parts of the guides into your answer.

Comment: Thought I did as considerations include: "minimum distances between targets, backstops and safe angles of approach" (which vary depending on terrain and target type) and "expect to use 1 acre per target"

Comment: No, you didn't, at least not well enough for the standards of this site.  Basically the only content *in this answer directly* is that minimum distances between targets, backstops, and angles are issues.  I know nothing about archery, and I could have guessed that.  The only real information you give is that it takes about one acre per target.  Imagine you asked about how to write a exchange sort routine, and someone answered *"Here is a link.  You have to use statements and stuff."*.  That's not how it's done here.

Comment: To put it another way, your answer is basically just the last sentence, and that by itself really isn't helpful